# Similaridade musical a partir de padrões de descritores de MPEG-7

Tags: áudio, matlab, mpeg

Estou desenvolvendo pesquisas na área de similaridade musical para recomendação de músicas e criei uma base de dados para teste com 1.000 músicas. Gostaria de criar uma *playlist* com 10 músicas semelhantes a uma música escolhida entre essas mil, utilizando descritores MPEG-7.

Eu extrai 30 segundos de cada música para ter um padrão de características extraídas pelos descritores MPEG-7. Eu não gostaria de gerar classificações de sons em gêneros músicas, somente criar uma *playlist* pelo ritmo similar ao da música selecionada. Se uma música lenta for selecionada, essa *playlist* será de músicas lentas (as dez mais similares).

Tentei extrair alguns descritores como *Audio Spectral Centroid*, *Audio Power*, o que me deu um vetor. Porém, utilizando o cálculo da distância euclidiana no MATLAB, não consegui uma similaridade muito boa. Como posso construir esse prototipo utilizando os descritores MPEG-7?

Eu extraí um vetor de características para os descritores Audio Spectral Centroid e o Audio Power onde em ambos, para 30 segundos, ficou um vetor de 1000 posições, pois a extração de características do sinal de audio ocorre a cada 30ms. A duvida justamente é em saber se estou utilizando os descritores certos para esse tipo de trabalho.

```xml
<AudioDescriptor xsi:type="AudioSpectrumCentroidType">
    <SeriesOfScalar hopSize="PT30N1000F" totalNumOfSamples="1002">
        <Raw> 0.0 -1.6024935 -0.6072393 -0.7425593 -0.8901987 -1.1543454 -1.1027017 -0.64731646 -0.96495366 -1.022632 -0.8076392 -0.993545 -0.66203004 -0.93275607 -1.1654149 -0.9243456 -1.2580872 -1.339062 -1.5594536 -1.5959411 -1.7814989 -1.6296328 -1.5468938 -1.0133578 -1.250789 -1.0111073......</Raw> 
    </SeriesOfScalar>
</AudioDescriptor>
```

Esse é uma das características extraídas, o Audio Spectrum Centroid, que indica o centro de gravidade da amplitude. Mas não sei ao certo qual descritor utilizar e como devo utilizar para isso.

Comment: Onde está sua dúvida sobre programação ??

Comment: É fato. O conceito é muito interessante. Mas o melhor é você mostrar seu código para *`Tentei extrair alguns descritores`* e *`utilizando o cálculo da distância euclidiana`*.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para incluir essas informações.

Comment: Olá. A sua pergunta é interessante e a pertiência dela ao escopo do site [está em discussão aqui](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/275/73)).

Comment: Eu não conheço muito do domínio de processamento de áudio, e por isso não me arrisco a escrever uma resposta. Mas, não me parece que a distância Euclidiana seja apropriada para características como as que você citou. Você já tentou utilizar o produto escalar normalizado (também chamado de [similaridade cosseno](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity)) para medir a similaridade entre seus vetores? Aqui tem uma sugestão de cálculo no Matlab: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14340447/2896619

Comment: Olá Luiz, irei dar uma estudada a respeito sim...muito obrigado. A duvida também é quais os descritores usar para esse tipo de projeto

Comment: Opa, por nada. Sobre os descritores, eu imagino que também se utilize a Transformada Rápida de Fourier e/ou Autovetores. Esse link da Wikipedia pode lhe ser útil: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_similarity

Comment: Eu sugeriria tentar fazer uma redução de dimensionalidade (usando PCA) antes de calcular a distância. Talvez consiga alguma melhora. Isso se os descritores forem bons, claro.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

O assunto é complexo e não é fácil responder sem entrar em alguns detalhes. Vou tentar de uma maneira simples abordar os pontos levantados pela pergunta, vamos lá:

Algo de extrema relevância ao se comparar ritmos é conhecer quantas batidas por minuto um áudio possui, claro que para efetuar este tipo de análise você vai precisar de uma janela maior, 30 milissegundos é insuficiente para mensurar *batidas por minuto* (bpm). Isso é de grande ajuda para conhecer se um determinado áudio possui um estilo lento ou mais agitado, mas só esta informação ainda não é o suficiente para conseguir bons resultados. Uma boa lista de descritores no domínio do tempo/frequência seria:

Descritores no domínio do tempo:

- *RMS (Root Mean Square)* - faz análise da energia em um sinal de áudio, pode ser útil para determinar se o áudio analisado possui grande intensidade ou não.
- *Zero Crossing Rate* - faz análise para saber quantas vezes um sinal de áudio cruzou o eixo x, possui uma analogia na variação do áudio.
- *Low Energy Rate* - faz uma análise da porcentagem(quantidade) dos
  frames capturados que estão abaixo da média do RMS, com isso você
  saberá a porcentagem dos frames que possui menos energia do que a
  média. Consequentemente, dá para saber se o áudio analisado está na maioria
  das vezes com intensidade maior ou não.

Descritores no domínio do Espectro:

- *Spectral Entropy* - calcula a entropia de um sinal de áudio, a
  entropia nada mais é do que a medida do desarranjo em determinado
  sistema. Deixe-me exemplificar, imagine que você possui dentro de
  uma caixa de sapato uma coleção de carrinhos e todos eles estão
  organizados (enfileirados) por cor, imagine agora que você tire um
  pouco fora de ordem isso (desarrume), neste momento você terá uma
  medida de entropia. Imagine agora que você pegue a caixa e balance
  forte, todos os carrinhos vão estar em desordem total caracterizando outra medida de entropia. Este tipo de característica deve ser útil na verificação de quão organizado um determinado sinal
  de áudio é.
- *Spectral Flux* - faz a medida do fluxo dos espectros. Lembrando que
  análise de sinais de áudio as análises são feitas dentro de
  Janelas (blocos), o Spectral Flux é calculado bloco a bloco, o bloco
  atual é subtraído do bloco anterior e os seus resultados são
  indicativos da quão rápido é a variação do sinal.
- *Spectral Irregularity* - faz a medida da irregularidade do sinal, ele
  funciona parecido com o Spectral Flux, esta função vai produzir um
  serrilhado, dentação nos resultados. Ele calcula a diferença dentro
  do bloco capturado e não bloco a bloco como é feito no Spectral Flux.
- *Spectral Centroid* - possui relação com o brilho do sinal, calcula a
  energia relativa entre a maior e menor frequência. Isto dá pistas no
  brilho do sinal.
- *Spectral RollOff* - Rolloff espectral é definido como a quantidade de
  vezes (frequência) em que a energia do espectro está abaixo de um
  determinado ponto. Tem indicações de uma onda assimétrica à direita.
- *Spectral Skewness* - calcula o grau de assimetria de um sinal de
  áudio, este descritor vai retorna valores de quão assimétrico um
  determinado frame é. Certamente este tipo de informação dá
  cateterísticas timbrais na forma de onda analisada.
- *Spectral Kurtosis*  - o Spectral Skewness calcula a assimetria do
  sinal e o Kurtosis calcula o grau de achatamento de uma onda.
- *MFCC (Mel-frequency cepstrum)* - coleta informações essenciais (coeficientes) que ajudam reconhecer padrões.

Agora que você sabe o que cada descritor faz, monte um vetor para cada bloco de análise, neste caso teremos:

- Os treze primeiros são os resultados dos coeficientes do MFCC
- O 14º valor é o mean da Centroid
- O 15º valor é o standard deviation(std) da Centroid
- 16º mean Irregularity
- 17º std(standard deviation) Irregularity
- 18º mean Entropy
- 19º std Entropy
- 20º mean Flux
- 21º std Flux
- 22º mean Kurtosis
- 23º std Kurtosis
- 24º mean Rolloff
- 25º std Rolloff
- 26º mean Skewness
- 27º std Skewness
- 28º mean RMS(Root Mean square)
- 29º std RMS(Root Mean square)
- 30º mean ZCR(Zero Crossing Rate)
- 31º std ZCR(Zero Crossing Rate)
- 32º LER(Low Energy Rate)

Depois do 32º ainda falta mais 5 descritores que são os rítmicos pegos pelo Beat Histogram (histograma da batida) ou seja no total você vai ter um vetor com 37 posições cada um deles descrevendo algo!

Para não estender muito, tente outros algoritmos de "procura por similaridade", além da distância euclidiana tente [KNN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm), [LSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing), [DP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) ou Redes Neurais (Random Forests, MLP).

Comment: Classe magistral, muchas gracias!